# Strip Antenna Impedance Control

Tags: pcb-design, rf, antenna, nrf24l01

I'm integrating an nRF24L01+ chip into a PCB I'm designing, but I'm a little confused about the best PCB antenna design.

I would like to make design a pcb stripline antenna, I have found the correct dimensions from this document:

https://www.cypress.com/file/136236/download

I understand that each Fab house is going to have different stackups. So should I specify that I need 50 ohm impedance control? If so what sort of parameters do I need to specify besides the impedance, ex frequency, tolerance?

Answer (score 0):

I generally select the manufacturer first and select the stackup first from what they have, as custom stackups are more expensive and really needed for simple things. From there you do your calculations and create the trace and all the necessary clearances.
Put a note on the copper layer with trace width and impedance you expect – most PCB houses know how to use this. And select impedance control option when ordering the PCBs.

Regarding tolerances – most good fabs will specify what tolerances you should expect for each class of manufacturing. Some can send you test reports for a fee.

Answer (score 0):

You design the stack-up (layers sequence), not the manufacturer.

Manufacturers use standard thickness pre-preg and core materials.

You are called to design your antenna starting from the stack-up and from manufacturers' pre-preg and core thicknesses.

If you want the manufacturer to measure in production the impedance of your transmission lines or PCB antennas be ready to pay extra costs.